# Sin acceso a crear plan de mantenimiento, teniendo privilegios como sysadmin

Tags: sql-server

Contexto:
Hace poco conseguí un trabajo como DBA Junior en una empresa local.
Me ordenaron hacer planes de mantenimiento sobre una base de datos y averiguando encontré que SQL Server, debería tener desde administración opciones para generar los mismos, siempre y cuando ingrese al servidor con un usuario que tenga permisos de sysadmin (según documentación de microsoft).

El hecho es que tengo tales permisos y aún así no tengo acceso
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier información relacionada es bien agradecida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es probable que no tengas una edición de SQL Server que sí pueda trabajar con planes de mantenimiento.

- Revisa con este comando la versión: SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
- Revisa si tienes soportado el SQL Server Agent: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15#SSMS

Si tienes una versión que no tenga soporte de Agent, no puedes crear tareas de mantenimiento.

Comment: Estimado, está en lo correcto.
La versión que manejo es "Express Edition (64-bit)", que, según la documentación de Microsoft (que correctamente recomendó), no tiene soporte de SQL Server Agent.  
Tendrá alguna sugerencia de como continuar desde este punto? Pregunto desde mi falta de experiencia como dba, en relación a si existe alguna herramienta externa que pueda aplicar para programar tareas de mantenimiento o si es necesario cambiar la tecnología ya sea actualizando a otra versión de SQL paga o bien cambiando el motor a por ejemplo MySQL, etc.

Comment: La mejor alternativa en este caso es usar Tareas Programadas en Windows que ejecuten los códigos de SQL que requieres. Te dejo aquí un enlace con todo el proceso descrito https://datoptim.com/tareas-programadas-con-sqlcmd/

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo ya enseguida reviso el link!